# No mapping defined for member result at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.FillUpdateProjection

Tags: c#, cassandra, asp.net-core-2.1, cassandra-3.0

I have a basic app with Cassandra data store, I am getting exception when I try to update the entity.

Here is entity model.

```
public class Log
{
    [ClusteringKey]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid ModifiedById { get; set; }

    [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.PartitionKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.PartitionKey]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public int LoggingLevel { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [Frozen]
    public IEnumerable<LogParamsCUDT> LogParams { get; set; }
}
```

How i am trying to update entity

```
var table = new Table<Log>(session);
var result = table.First().Execute();
```

**Code given below works fine:**

```
table.Where(w=>w.Id==result.Id && !result.IsDeleted && w.CreationDate==result.CreationDate)
.Select(s => new Log {Url="testing update" }).Update().Execute();
```

**Code given below throws error:**

```
table.Where(w=>w.Id==result.Id && !result.IsDeleted && w.CreationDate==result.CreationDate)
.Select(s => result).Update().Execute();
```

> **InvalidOperationException: No mapping defined for member: result**

Do I have to map each property with new object or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to provide an expression with assignments to the columns you want to update so here are two examples that work:

```
table.Where(w=>w.Id==result.Id && !result.IsDeleted && w.CreationDate==result.CreationDate)
.Select(s => new Log {Url="testing update" }).Update().Execute();

table.Where(w=>w.Id==result.Id && !result.IsDeleted && w.CreationDate==result.CreationDate)
.Select(s => new {Url="testing update" }).Update().Execute();
```

I recommend the first one because if you mistype a property name the code won't even compile.

Both of those examples result in the following prepared statement:

```
UPDATE <KEYSPACE>.<TABLE> SET Url = ? WHERE Id = ? AND IsDeleted = ? AND CreationDate = ?
```

Also you might want to change `!result.IsDeleted` to `w.IsDeleted == !result.IsDeleted`. I believe `!result.IsDeleted` works because of the `!` symbol but if you try to use just `result.IsDeleted` it will fail because the driver expects an expression with two "sides" (otherwise it won't know what to compare it against).

If you want to update the entire record without having to specify every column then I recommend looking at the Mapper (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.11/features/components/mapper/), because that's not currently supported with Linq2Cql:

```
IMapper mapper = new Mapper(session);
mapper.Update(record);
```

Comment: I think You misunderstood the question. i am trying to pass the entity object for updating the whole record which fails.

Comment: I understood but I failed to clarify that point. That is not currently supported so I suggest looking at Mapper. I've updated the answer.